# Topological spaces homotopic equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology

Give 2 topological spaces i remember that: X and Y are homotopic equivalent if there exist continuous maps $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ and $g:X\longrightarrow Y$ such that $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $id_X$ and $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $id_Y$.

Intuitively, two spaces X and Y are homotopy equivalent if they can be transformed into one another with continuity (bending, shrinking, expanding,...).

My quest is: 0) if $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous, then $X$ is homotopic equivalent to $Im(f)$ ?

I call also:
1) if $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous and $X$ is a contractible space, then $Im(f)$ is a contractible space ? (a contractible space is a space homotopic equivalent to one-point space $*$).

2) if $\sigma:\Delta_p\longrightarrow X$ is a $p$-singular simplex of a space $X$, then $Im \sigma$ is a contractible space?

Obviously $0)\Longrightarrow 1)\Longrightarrow 2)$ but i am not sure which statements are true.

Comment: What *is* true is that if $X$ is contractible then any function $f\colon X \to Y$ is null-homotopic, which does not mean the same thing as $im(f)$ being contractible.

Comment: It's called "homotopy equivalent" not "homotopic equivalent".

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample to all three, take $X = [0,1] = \Delta_1$ and $Y = \mathbb R^2$, and let $f(t) = (\cos(2 \pi t),\sin(2 \pi t))$, so $Im(f) = S^1$.